# Error with dag in gRbase package

Tags: r, plot, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to write a DAG with the R package gRbase, but it doesn't seem to work, and it seems that I have all libraries installed.This is what I write:

```
library(gRbase) 
dag11 <- dag( ~a*b + b*c*d) 
plot(dag11)
```

And the console returns:

```
Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

What does this error mean in this context? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Not familiar with `gRbase`, but from the examples made in the documentation, it uses `:` instead of `*`. Can it be the cause of your error (can't ckeck myself, since I don't have `grBase` installed and don't want to)?

Comment: I can check, it is supposed to work either one or the other.

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: To plot it you need to load the `graph` package ... although i think the plot is done through `Rgraphviz` .. Try `Rgraphviz::plot(dag11)` or `graph::plot(dag11)`

Comment: With the `graph` package works!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following library will solve the problem:

```
library(Rgraphviz)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you!